# Integrals that can be solved completely both by u-substitution and integration by parts

Tags: integration

Consider the integral $\int x(x^2+1)\,dx$.  Besides using algebra to rewrite the integral as $\int x^3+x\,dx$, it can be solved in two ways:

1. Using $u$-substitution with $u=x^2+1$.
2. Using integration by parts with $u=x$ and $dv=x^2+1$.  (Or the reverse works too.)

I am searching for more integrals that can be handled entirely using only substitution or only integration by parts.  In particular, I would like to find examples that are more interesting than simply the product of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

One of my personal favourites would be:
$$I=\int e^x\sin(x)dx$$
if you do IBP a few times you will get the answer but by writing it as:
$$I=\int e^x\Im(e^{ix})dx=\Im\int e^{(1+i)x}dx$$
It is very clear to see and only requires simple understanding of complex numbers, this result also gives you the answer to the similar integral:
$$\int e^x\cos(x)dx$$
and using the exponential definitions of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ can be used to solve the integrals:
$$\int e^x\cosh(x)dx$$
$$\int e^x\sinh(x)dx$$

---

If you are interested in other commonly used methods there are ones such as Feynman substitution (dummy variable) or converting to double integrals and changing the order of integration (if allowed). Many integrals end up being defined in terms of standardised functions as well such as:

1. Beta function
2. Gamma function
3. Zeta function

The list goes on and on...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem possible to evaluate $\int e^x\cosh x$ using IBP... No matter how you choose $u$ and $dv$ you always end up canceling two integrals and getting something like $e^x\sinh x-e^x\cosh x=C$.

Comment: Ill have a look myself but if its anything like the equivalent with cos you end up with an expression like $I=f(x)-I$ which you can clearly rearrange for $I$

Comment: sin and cos switch signs when differentiated, but cosh and sinh do not.  As such, you get an equation like $I=f(x)+I$, which collapses to $0=f(x)$.

That said, you can avoid this by instead considering something like $\int e^{2x}\cosh x\,dx$.

Comment: yes that is a good point, in any case IBP is still not the best choice haha

Comment: @HenryLee Hi, could you please explain how you solved $\int e^x \sin{x}$ using the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$? Or point me to any resources that show how you solved this (and got a final answer)? Trying to understand for an assignment that I'm doing that has a similar question, but I can't seem to find the relevant information in my lecture notes and I'm still learning about complex integration so I'm not really sure what to do with it :/

Comment: @Applesauce44 just treat $1+i$ as a constant, say $a=1+i$ then you have $\int e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}=\frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{1+i}$ now multiply by the complex conjugate on top and bottom so $\frac{1-i}{1-i}$ and this will give you $\frac{1-i}{2}e^xe^{ix}$ now use the fact that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Finally take the Imaginary part and you will get your answer

Comment: @HenryLee ohhh I see I see, thank you! Sorry for the trouble!